# django template

Tags: html, django

I have a drop-down list

In my template,

```
    <form name="languages" method="post">
        <select id="langSelect" onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
           <option>en (default)</option>
           {% for ele in comments.languages.all %}
               <option>{{ele.lang}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <div><a  onclick="getIndex()">Submit</a></div>

    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function getIndex(){
    var x = document.getElementById("langSelect").selectedIndex;            
}
```

In the html:

{{obj.comments.all.index.value}}

How can I get the value of index from getIndex() and pass it back to django template

obj.comments[index].value and index = getIndex()

{{obj.comments.all.index.value}}?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for), you can use the forloop.counter0 and drop completely the getIndex() javascript function

i don't know exactly what you need, but you can then do something like

```
{{ c.comments.all.index.text forloop.counter0 }}
```

aka: pass the forloop.counter0 value to what you need

nb: i know nothing about {{c.comments.all.index.text}} so maybe my syntax won't work, you have to adapt it to your real usecase